# How to format all the files simultaneously in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, format

Having different types of files - `.ts, .js, .html, .css, .scss & .json` in 1 project.

Any extension to install which will help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format all files in a Visual Studio Code project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43666270/how-do-i-format-all-files-in-a-visual-studio-code-project)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this extension, you have to select files manually which you want to format.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lacroixdavid1.vscode-format-context-menu#overview